# How to overlay a tikz grid with text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, grids

As a teacher I would like to create some work sheets with gridded space after the question for the students to type their solutions in. I used tikz in order to make a 4mm x 4mm grid and this works just fine.

However, I want to have a solution paper, which is the same sheet but instead of an empty grid I would like to have the solution written on that grid. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. // Please add at least some screenshots and sketches to your question, what you are after. If you can, list also code (which is this places "currency".) // Would it be sufficient to have the grid as background? Do you expect students to write on a print-out, or does it have to be inside a pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no code there's a good amount of guessing. In my own school class I use something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifsolution
\newcommand*{\grid}{}
\def\grid(#1,#2)#3{%
   \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]{%
      \draw[gray,step=.4](0,0)grid(.4*#1,-.4*#2);
      \node[align=flush left,text width=.4*#1cm-3mm,anchor=north west] (text) at (0,0.1) {\strut\ifsolution#3\fi} ;
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\solutiontrue
Hello \grid(4,7){world! How are you?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The *x* and *y* values here are just the numbers of "boxes" (in your case 4mm each). The boolean `\ifsolution` controls the appearance of the solution.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I have hoped for. Thanks for the quick help! (For (un-)hiding the solutions I have a similar system then what is shown here: https://tobiw.de/tbdm/lueckentexte)